# Random scrolling while reloading uitableviewcell, iOs/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am developing news feed and I am using uitableview to display data. I am loading each cell data synchronically in other thread and use protocol method to display loaded data:

```
func nodeLoaded(node: NSMutableDictionary) {
    for var i = 0; i < nodesArray.count; ++i {
        if ((nodesArray[i]["id"] as! Int) == (node["id"] as! Int)) {
            nodesArray[i] = node
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(false)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I scrolling down (while tableview updating), tableview push me on the top. I was searching answer on this problem, but nothing helps me. I already tried to disable animation:

```
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(false)
```

2)

```
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

But the story always the same.
I have the desired effect when I simply don't use `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)`
, but in this case data reload only if I scroll down and then return back to cell.

Maybe the problem is that I use auto layout and tableview recalculate its height every time? But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I want to understand why you don't want the animation. A slide in out animation when cells tell the user that something has arrived or gone away. If you really don't want the animations and want to stop the random scrolling try this: `tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` and if you want animations change the None to something else from the enum.

Comment: Oh, I thought that random scrolling starts bcs of animation . I tried reloadSections, but id didn't help =(

Comment: what did you do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the reload mechanism yourself.

Iterate over all visible cells (`tableView.visibleCells`) and apply the same logic to them as you would in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If you need the index path to perform this update, you can ask the table view for it (`-indexPathForCell:`).

Comment: So if I change my visible cell like this: cell.label.text = "new", then info in uitableview will update? I tried and it not working , mb I am doing something wrong

Comment: What 'info' in `UITableView` are you talking about?

Comment: Are you doing the update on the main queue? Try doing this instead `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { cell.label.text = "new" })`

Comment: I can't update visible cells =( 
Can you tell whats wrong?


var cells = table.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as! [NSIndexPath]
                for var j = 0; j < cells.count; ++j {
                    var test = cells[j].row
                }
When I call tableView.visibleCells looks like it return 1 000 000+ values and my xCode not responding in debug mode